# Where are aggregation pipeline saved in MongoDb Compass?

Tags: aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I know that starting from Compass 1.21 saved aggregation pipelines are moved to filesystem as stated [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-3884), but I was not able to find where!!
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved!!
Using:

```
sudo strace -f -t -e trace=file -p COMPASS_PID
```

Is possible to trace files opened by Compass Process ID (COMPASS_PID above).
In this way I found that aggregation pipelines are saved by Compass as json file inside path:

```
/home/<current_user>/.config/MongoDB\ Compass/SavedPipelines/61b1c7079f9d09c1caf3b3c5.json
```

This, at least, in Kubuntu 21.10.